# PHP get same time everyday with time() function

Tags: php, time

How can I get a certain time everyday in PHP with `time()` function?

For example, 9 AM everyday.

```
$curTime    = time() + (30 * 60);
```

Comment: nice, since you didn't answer, I will accept the other guy. Thanks tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

```
$nine_am = mktime(9,0,0);
```

Using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$nine_am = strtotime('09:00');
```